# Celsius to Fahrenheit and Fahrenheit to Celsius table (C++)

Tags: c++, function, methods, double, converters

I am making a table that consists of celsius values that convert to Fahrenheit and the other way around as well.

This is what I want the code to output:

```
Celsius       Fahrenheit     |   Fahrenheit       Celsius
40.0           104.0         |     120.0           48.89
39.0           102.2         |     110.0           43.33
```

The problem is that with the functions I cannot get the second part to output on the other side of the table.

This is what the code outputs (not what I want):

```
Celsius       Fahrenheit     |   Fahrenheit       Celsius
40.0           104.0         |     
39.0           102.2         |     
120.0           48.89
110.0           43.33
```

this is the code I have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double celsiusToFahrenheit(double f1);
double fahrenheitToCelsius(double c2);

int main(){

    double f1;

    double c2;

    cout<< left <<setw(10)<< left << "Celsius" << right<< setw(10) << "Fahrenheit | " << setw(10) << "Fahrenheit" << right << setw(10)<< "Celsius"<< endl;

    cout<< left<< setw(10)<< left << celsiusToFahrenheit(f1) << right << setw(10)<< fahrenheitToCelsius(c2)<< endl;
    


    return 0;
}

double celsiusToFahrenheit(double f1){


for(double c1 = 40.0; c1 > 30.00; c1--){
        
        f1 = (c1 * (9.0/5.0)) + 32.0;

       cout<< left <<setw(10)<< left << c1<< right<< setw(10) << f1 << right<<" | "<< endl;
    }

    return f1;

}

double fahrenheitToCelsius(double c2){


for(double f2 = 120.0; f2 > 29.00; f2--){
        
         c2 = ((5.0/9.0) * (f2 - 32.0));

         cout<< left <<setw(10)<< left << f2<< right<< setw(10) << c2 << right<< endl;

    }


    return c2;

}
```

Comment: Tip: Make a conversion function that takes one temperature and returns one converted value. These two do a whole bunch of other stuff that confuses their *responsibility*. What you really need is a presenter function that draws your table rows, another pair that does the specific conversions, and possibly a third table generator function that takes a range, a converter function (`std::function` or lambda, ideally), and bangs out the table.

Comment: @Andrew Tang: Is youre question about fahrenheit and celsius or is your question about "How to draw a table by using left, right, setw(10), and endl in streams?". Please, change the question. Background: The queue to suggest edits is full. Hence, I cant change the questions for stackoverflow, and its technical reasons. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Doing printing inside of something *being printed* is probably where things are going wrong here, but in particular, `endl` inside of those functions.

You're cutting the line off early. Quick fix is to get rid of that:

```cpp
cout<< left <<setw(10)<< left << c1<< right<< setw(10) << f1 << right<<" | ";
```

Yet the problem here is you iterate in the middle of printing these, which is causing a whole ton of structural problems.